# Creating Area Chart in R from xtabs Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, charts

I have a data frame that I created using xtabs.

My goal is to create an area graph / sand chart using this data frame, I'm just not entirely sure how to declare the axes.

```
vg <- read.csv("vgdata.csv")

df <- data.frame(vg)

graph <- xtabs(Sales ~ Year + Genre, df)
print(graph)
```

Output:

```
       Genre
Year    Action    RPG   Shooter
2005         3      2         2
2006         1      1         3
2007         3      3         4
2008         1      5         8
2009         4      7         7
2010         4      5         2
```

Typically I would use Sales, Genre, Year, etc as variables of my graph, but these don't exist because of how it was created using xtabs. I simply have graph as a defined variable.

I would like to have the years on the x axis and the sales data on the y axis with the genre being labels. I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this with the format I already have. The reason I chose xtabs is because I had several video game titles under action, RPG, and shooter for each year and it was a convenient way to sum them to get a data frame of total sales per year.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possible ways you can plot your results. For this example I'm using data from your last SO question.

Assuming you use `xtabs` as described:

```
result <- xtabs(Sales ~ Year + Genre, df)
```

You can convert to a data frame:

```
plot_data <- as.data.frame(result)
plot_data

  Year   Genre Freq
1 2005  Action    3
2 2006  Action    0
3 2007  Action    1
4 2005     RPG    0
5 2006     RPG    4
6 2007     RPG    2
7 2005 Shooter    3
8 2006 Shooter    0
9 2007 Shooter    3
```

For the area plot, you can make `Year` numeric instead of a factor for use on the x axis:

```
plot_data$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(plot_data$Year))
```

Then plot with `geom_area`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Year, y = Freq, fill = Genre)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2005:2007)
```

**Plot**

[image: area plot with xtabs results]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = 1:8, Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), Genre = c("Action", "Action", "Shooter", 
"RPG", "RPG", "Action", "Shooter", "RPG"), Sales = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```